# Property 'utm' does not exist on type 'typeof

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, leaflet

I'm doing the front-end of a project using Angular 10.

In it I'm using leaflet to display maps but there was a need to install the dependency [(leaflet.utm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.utm/v/0.0.4), but I have no idea how to distinguish the `L` from the two libraries (leaflet and leatlet.utm).

**module installation:**

```
npm i leaflet.utm@0.0.4
```

**import:**

```js
...
import * as L from 'leaflet';
...
```

**Code I'm attempting to use:**

```js
var item = L.utm({x: 467486.3, y: 4101149.3, zone: 30, band: 'S'});
```

**Thrown Exception:**

> ```
> Property 'utm' does not exist on type 'typeof import("../node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'.ts(2339)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `leaflet.utm` too:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.utm';
```

Comment: it worked, combined with npm install --save @types/leaflet.utm